# How to make VIM create a new window below the current as default?

Tags: vim

VIM create new window above the current or on the left side as default.
To use VIM more naturally, I want it to work oppositely, and I have set

```
:set splitright
:set splitbelow
```

This works when I split a window using command

```
:split
```

or

```
:vsplit
```

However, this fails when I create a new empty window using command

```
:new
```

or

```
:vnew
```

Is there any solution for the second situation?

Answer (score 7):

You have only to add "below" before the command:

```
:below new 

:below vnew
```

and from `:help below`

> :rightb[elow] {cmd}
>   :bel[owright] {cmd}
>
> Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window,
>                   **it will be opened right (vertical split) or below (horizontal
>                   split) the current window**.  Overrules 'splitbelow' and
>                   'splitright'.
>                   Doesn't work for |:execute| and |:normal|.

For the mapping discussed in the comments you can use this one:

```
:cnoremap new ^Bbelow ^Enew
```

you get:

^B by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>b</kbd>

^E by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>e</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this works actually. But I want to make it default so that I don't need to type any words other than 'new' itself.

Comment: `:set splitbelow` works fine for me I don't know why it is not the case for you but if you want you can add a mapping in command line. I can show you how if you want ?

Comment: You have reminded me. It's my carelessness that caused the problem. I configured the setting before, but didn't add it to the vimrc file, so it didn't work when I restarted Vim. It works now since I set it again and add it to the vimrc file. Thank you.